# SQL where clause for a named table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How do i do a where clause to check the age show below when i don't have an age field to check it against? I'm using oracle DB.

```
select LNAME || ', ' || FNAME as "Name", 
       TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY') - TO_CHAR(DOB,'YYYY') as AGE 
  from STAFF
 where AGE = (select min(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY') - TO_CHAR(DOB,'YYYY')) 
                from STAFF);
```

Comment: Age is not generally the current year minus the year of birth. You probably want the months_between sysdate and the date of birth divided by 12. Also, subtracting a string from another string seems like a bad habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some example on existing Oracle table:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
 SELECT ename as "Name"
      , TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY') - TO_CHAR(hiredate,'YYYY') as AGE 
  FROM scott.emp
)
WHERE age = (SELECT min(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY') - TO_CHAR(hiredate,'YYYY')) FROM scott.emp)
/

Name    AGE
----------------
SCOTT   26
ADAMS   26
```

You may also add analytic functions to partition by age or any other field for example or simply order by age asc to see all emps in output removing where...

Comment: Ty worked nicely. Thanks for keeping my original code as well.

Answer (score 1):

To select the youngest staff member:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  *
        from    STAFF
        order by
                DOB desc
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   rownum = 1
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6aafa/1/0)

Comment: Im not quite sure i understand. I understand sort of what you are doing but how would i use this?

Comment: Your query looks like you're searching for the youngest staff member.  This query will return that.  If you're looking for something else, consider editing your question with more details.